# Create an EXFAT partition on a NTFS external HD

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive, ntfs, exfat

Is it possible to create an exFAT partition on a NTFS external HD? I just wanna backup stuff from an old macbook, so I thought maybe I can just create a new exFAT partition instead of full reformatting (exHD is half full) Problem is win7 Disk Management's New Simple Volume Wizard only offers NTFS in the Format Partition step.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Practically speaking  NTFS is a file system, as is exFAT - its an either/or choice, not a layered one.  Filesystem's sit on partitions, not raw disks (**most of the time. I am aware of the exceptions, but they can be ignored here**)

What you can do is shrink the NTFS filesystem and partition and then add a second partition which uses exFAT.

You don't have to use Windows (and indeed you should be sent to your room for running Windows 7 at all) to repartition disks - You might want to look at a USB based Linux system to boot off a pen drive and then run something like like KDE Partition manager (which supports exFAT) or the more common gparted (but settle for a fat32 partition.

You can alternatively use something that allows you to use NTFS in a Mac (https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/#) or set up file sharing on your Windows box and copy the files to the NTFS disk on the Windows 7 box over the network.

Comment: OK thx. The thing is I already shrank the volume (2tb exHD) creating 100 gb of unallocated space. Then I wanted to create the exFAT partition. So is this what you are saying: yes, it is possible but not with win7 Disk Management tool? Is "shrinking a filesystem" the same as "shrinking a volume" Maybe this question is idiotic, but I am obviously not an engineer or techie. If yes and yes, is there any free tool out there to do what I am trying to do? I have dual boot win10 in my PC also. Thx again.

Comment: I can't robustly answer your question because I spend my life on Linux systems, but yeah, when I said volume I meant partition. Google tells me "AOMI partition standard" will run on Windows and will allow you to exFAT format that partition.